# manually adding to snapshot in maven repository

Tags: maven, repository

If I publish a version like foo-2.0-20150506.110000-1 to a maven repository, will it be considered if something depends on foo-2.0-SNAPSHOT?

To be more precise: Is their any magic in the SNAPSHOT command or is a SNAPSHOT dependency just resolved to the newest time stamp, no matter where it came from?

Comment: What kind of command are you talking about? You simply define a version something like `1.0-SNAPSHOT` which will be stored into a repository manager which will make something like `1.0-20150506.114533-1` under the hood and will give you back the newest one if you define `-U` on command line..otherwise Maven will check only based on the [update policy ](https://maven.apache.org/settings.html#Repositories)..

Comment: My aim is to add something to 2.0-SNAPSHOT, but to control the timestamp, i.e. I want to define the internal name myself (this is for synchronisation of two repositories).

Comment: The simple answer to this: Not possible, cause such thing is defined (or to be more accurate generated) by the repository manager (for example Nexus)...In which way would you like to synchronize repositories?

Comment: Actually, I want to move an artifact from 2.0-DEV-SNAPSHOT to 2.0-RC-SNAPSHOT while keeping its name.

Comment: Hm..maybe i misunderstand a thing. You have artifacts with version `2.0-DEV-SNAPSHOT` and deployed them to a repository manager...Now you want to change the version into `2.0-RC-SNAPSHOT`? Why not changing the version in your pom files and make an other deploy on the new location? It sounds you misunderstand the idea of SNAPSHOT's or i misunderstand a thing...

Comment: I know what a snapshot is but actually I need the SNAPSHOT behaviour and (in some other places) the concrete versions.

Comment: Either it is a SNAPSHOT or not...by concrete version you mean a release version something like `2.0.0-RC1`?

Comment: I mean something like RC1, which should also being part of RC-SNAPSHOT. I know that this is difficult ...

Comment: But on the other hand, this is how it is done now (without Maven), having versions RC1, RC2, RC3, ... and SNAPSHOT is always the last one.

Comment: So you can simply make a release which is called `2.0.0-RC1`, `2.0.0-RC2` and finally `2.0.0`? Apart from that. The resolution for SNAPSHOT's is based on the default update policy which is by default that after 24 hours the existence of a newer version (SNAPSHOT) will be checked. This can be forced by using `-U ..` ...

Comment: if I make versions like 2.0.0-RC1, 2.0.0-RC2, I cannot use the SNAPSHOT mechanism. The problem is that I need to use both (fixed versions and SNAPSHOT) at once. This may be "anti-maven", but it is not my decision.